# How to map user permissions with view in PHP,HTML?

Tags: php, html, dom, permissions, crm

I am stuck in a situation while I was designing a CRM in php. I need to design various user groups with various permissions. Now consider a situation;

I have two user groups `group1` and `group2`.

Now users under `group1` can see a button called `button1` in a html page but users under `group2` can't.

Groups will be created by end user and each group permission can be modified later as needed. I mean if end user wants to give permission to `group2` users to be able to see the `button1` that can be done anytime later.

How can I accommodate this functionality in my existing code in a plugin basis. I mean I don't want to change my existing code much.

For your information I am using the REST API concept that means I am not using any PHP base template engine while rendering view.

Do I need to create a different view for each group?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Nothing in fact. Can't get the starting point. My final thinking was making different view for each group. But main issue here is when a new group 'll be added then I need to make a view(html page) dynamically; and I stopped thinking here :(  .